# In a Dictionary TryGetValue, how do I write the out parameter (and get it's values) if it's part of a class?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, extension-methods, trygetvalue

Past question thread and link to fullpast code [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040879/c-sharp-calling-a-dictionary-within-an-extension-class?noredirect=1#comment73169223_43040879)

I create my dictionary with a class for a parameter so it can hold two `string` values. Now I'm trying to write a `TryGetValue` to `out` both of the strings in this class:

```
public class DictionaryInitializer
{
    public class DictionarySetup
    {
        public string theDescription { get; set; }
        public string theClass { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, there's `theDescription` and `theClass` nested in the `DictionarySetup`. Then I would create the dictionaries using that class here:

```
    public class DictionaryInit
    {
        //IS_Revenues data
        public Dictionary<int, DictionarySetup> accountRevenue = new Dictionary<int, DictionarySetup>()
            {
                { 400000, new DictionarySetup {theDescription="Call", theClass="Revenues"}}
            };
        public Dictionary<int, DictionarySetup> accountExpenses = new Dictionary<int, DictionarySetup>()
            {
                {790100, new DictionarySetup { theDescription="Currency Hedge", theClass="Other income/expense"}}
            };
    }
```

Then, my extension method where I plan to use my `TryGetValue` on the dictionary:

```
    public void DictionaryUseKey(int MapCode, int MapKey, int rowindex, Dictionary<int, DictionarySetup> AccountLexicon)
    {
        AccountLexicon[1] = new DictionarySetup();
        DictionarySetup Classes;
        DictionarySetup Descriptions;
        //Saw the above code in another thread, not sure if it's what I should be doing but it seems pretty close to what I want, however, I don't know how to specify the DictionarySetup.theDescription for example;
        AccountLexicon.TryGetValue(MapKey, out Classes);
        {
            //I want to be able to write theDescription and theClass into string variables for use below if the `TryGetValue` returns true, but it seems to me that it can only out one value? How does this work?
            DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].Value =  ?? how do I write something like...  theValues.theDescription;
            DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[11].Value = ?? how do I write something like...  theValues.theClass;
        }
    }
```

Lastly, I call the extension method in my event like so:

```
    private void btnMapper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex < DGVMain.RowCount; rowindex++)
        {
            int accountKey = Convert.ToInt32(DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].Value);
            int projCode = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[7].Value));
            int deptCode = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[9].Value));
            int AbsoluteKey = Math.Abs(accountKey);
            while (AbsoluteKey >= 10) { AbsoluteKey /= 10; }
            while (deptCode >= 10) { deptCode /= 10; }
            theDictionary = new DictionaryInit();
            DictionaryUseKey(deptCode, accountKey, theDictionary.accountRevenue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any user-defined extension methods in your question.

Comment: You can only use variables with out-parameters (and ref-parameters for that matter). From your words, it looks like you're trying to use a property instead.

Comment: @Amy Sorry, I don't know what these are called exactly. Functions? Just methods? The term extension method was thrown around with examples like the one I wrote above: DictionaryUseKey(deptCode, accountKey, theDictionary.accountRevenue);

Comment: 'Extension method' has a very specific meaning in C#: it's a static method that can be called as if it's a member method. They can be used to provide additional functionality for existing types, but they're essentially just syntactic sugar. You're not using them here, though.

Comment: @Arvayne No apology needed.  This is why we're here, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `TryGetValue` method will returns a boolean value represents the presence of the specified key, if the key is found, the corresponding value will be stored in the out parameter. Here in your case the out parameter is `Classes` and are defined in your code like this: `DictionarySetup Classes`. which means in case the key is present in the Dictionary means corresponding `DictionarySetup` object will be stored in the  `Classes` so you can access the `theDescription` and `theClass` from  `Classes`; Consider the code below:

```
 if(AccountLexicon.TryGetValue(MapKey, out Classes))
 {
    DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].Value =  Classes.theDescription;
    DGVMain.Rows[rowindex].Cells[11].Value = Classes.theClass;
 }
```

Comment: Ah, so I was on the right track it seems. Let me test your suggestion.